# inserting integer into linked list in ascending order

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm trying to insert a new element into a linked list in ascending order, my code for inputting 3,1,9,7,5 outputs 1,1,1,1,1,1  however the output I want is 1,3,5,7,9

head is actually in a private instance variable for the class List and this is a member function

It is called as:

`List a;`
 `a.insertInOrder(3); a.insertInOrder(1); a.insertInOrder(9);   a.insertInOrder(7); insertInOrder(5);`

the output is 1,1,1,1,1

```
          void List::insertInOrder( int data) {

              Node *newNode = new Node; 
               newNode->data=data;

              if(head == null || head->data > data) { 
                 newNode->next = head; 
                 head = newNode; 
              }
              else{ 
                 Node *cur = head; 

                 while(cur->next != null && current->next->data < data) 
                   cur = cur->next; 
                 newNode->next = cur->next;
                 cur->next = newNode;
              } 
         }
```

Comment: What is the question?  

I see two issues:  

1. data is not stored into list - because of it is not assigned to newNode->data  

2. If you want a sorted linked list why you always check 'data' against 'nextC' instead of 'cur'?

Comment: @VladimirM thank you for that catch, I changed it to current->next->data but the output is still the same. I removed nextC

Comment: InsertInorder function looks ok to me. Are output function and function that adds items ok, too?

Comment: while its usually good to limit code to just the relevant section - there is possibly an issue with how you call InsertInorder or how you print, could you post that code as well?

Comment: Please, show me your output code. I copied your code, add List & Node simplest classes and did:
`List l; l.insertInOrder(3); l.insertInOrder(1); insertInOrder(9);  l.insertInOrder(3); Node *h = l.head; while (h) { cout << h->data << << std::endl;  h = h->next; } `  
The output is 1, 3, 3, 9

Comment: What code are you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

Seems mostly valid, but:

> ```
>        while(cur->next != null && current->next->data < data)
> ```

Here you refer to "cur" in one clause, and "current" in the other clause. 
"current' does no appear to exist, but perhaps you have globals?

But, even that would just screw up the ordering, so I suspect the error is in your output code, rather than your sort code.

Answer (score -1):

You aren't incrementing `nextC`, so your while loop is comparing `data` to just one number. `cur` does nothing since you aren't using it in the conditional like you are with `nextC`.

```
while(cur->next != null && nextC->data < data) //nextC->data is set only once
                   cur = cur->next; //cur incremented, but for what?
```

Comment: I updated the while loop, however the result is still the same